# Compositing Workflow/How to compose a render after restarting Blender?

Tags: rendering, freestyle, compositing-nodes, viewlayers

I'm new to Blender (coming from C4D) and currenty working on an architectural visualisation like this:

[image]
*The Image is a placeholder because I can't show the project.*

I made three view layers

1. Clay Render
2. Texture Render
3. Freestyle Layer

After rendering I combined all the view layers to my final render and everything is fine.

After restarting Blender the render was gone.

**Now I need your help:**

- How do I continue working on a composition in Blender 2.80 after restarting?
- How do I save the Render with all passes and cryptomattes to work on
  it later?
- How do I compose multiple renders with the same composition node system? For example a different camera.

Normally I compose my images in Photoshop, but I want to try it in Blender, because it seems so much easier and quicker.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is the FileOutput Node.

here is a basic Setup for your 3 Layer.
check the docs for renderlayer in Blender and you are good to go.

you can do a lot more then saving files with the compositing context, so have look and do some experimenting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Switch the 3d view into a compositor view. Arm your compositing network. Make a new workspace tab by duplicating the current. This will save everything with tool position and settings. Save blend file. All your compositor images renders must be saved in hdd, so next session they will not unplug.
Go to passes tab on right side properties tab, scroll down, mark cryptomatte objects. On the render layer node in the compositor plug cryptomatte out plugs into (shift+a) cryptomatte key, use picker to drive the matte.
Welcome to Blender 2.8. You'll love it.

Comment: So do I have to create my network in compositing first to save the images after rendering? I don't know how to hold the multipass data after rendering for the next blender session.

Comment: Ok I think you are refering to the image node in the compositor. They come right off the cache. UNLESS after you render THEN you RE-add them on an image path AGAIN from the path where you saved them on your hard drive. This "appear" dissaopear behavior in 2.79 is due to caching.